# Ajax autocomplete with gson on jsp

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, autocomplete, gson

I have problem about autocomplete with ajax.
I take datas from my java class to ajax jsp file.
But i cant append it to my listing area.

index.jsp

```
<head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $("#keyWord2").keyup(function(){
               if($(this).val().length>4){
                   fill_data($(this).val());
               }//endif

               if($(this).val().length<4){
                  $("#show").html(""); 
                  $("#show").css("display","none"); 
               }//endif
          });//end keyup function 
        });//end document ready function

  function fill_data(aranan){
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajaxSearch.jsp",
         data:"name="+encodeURIComponent(aranan), 
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(){  
             alert("success"); 
             $("#show").css("display","block");
             $("#show").html("");      
         $.each(data, function(i, item) {
             $("#show").append("<div >"+item.clientNumber+"</div>");
         });//end each function
         }//end success function
    });//end ajax
}//end fill_data

</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="keyWord2" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50"/>
        <div style=" display: none; " id="show"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

i call my datas from ajaxSearch.jsp and it returns me the list.But function doesnt come to success it doesnt show my element whose id is "show" and doesnt alert success.

Comment: show us the `ajaxSearch` page and also check for the errors in the console

Comment: thanks for helping, i solved it on ajaxSearch jsp side.

Comment: No issues . Always check the return values for the server side pages while using AJAX . it is the part where mistakes are made :)